# Collapsing rows where some are all NA, and columns are a mixture of factor, character and numeric class

Tags: r

There are some similar problems on Stack Overflow to this one here, but I haven't found a solution that addresses this problem with a data frame that has a mixture of column classes.

I have a dataframe, df:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", 
"ID1", "ID1", "ID1"), COLOUR = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("BLUE", "RED"), class = "factor"), 
    DATE = structure(c(17378, 17378, 17378, 17378, 17378, 17400, 
    17925, 17925, 17925), class = "Date"), size1 = c(NA, 496.4647, 
    332.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 23, NA), size2 = c(NA, NA, 90, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), length1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 343.8446, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), length2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), width1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), width2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    34.682, NA), group1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "CAT!"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

# A tibble: 9 x 10
  ID    COLOUR DATE        siz1 size2 length1 length2 width1 width2 group1
  <chr> <fct>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> 
1 ID1   RED    2017-07-31   NA     NA     NA       NA     NA   NA   NA    
2 ID1   RED    2017-07-31  496.    NA     NA       NA     NA   NA   NA    
3 ID1   RED    2017-07-31  332.    90     NA       NA     NA   NA   NA    
4 ID1   RED    2017-07-31   NA     NA     NA       NA     NA   NA   NA    
5 ID1   RED    2017-07-31   NA     NA    344.      NA     NA   NA   NA    
6 ID1   RED    2017-08-22   NA     NA     NA       NA     NA   NA   NA    
7 ID1   RED    2019-01-29   NA     NA     NA       NA     NA   NA   NA    
8 ID1   RED    2019-01-29   23     NA     NA       NA     NA   34.7 NA    
9 ID1   RED    2019-01-29   NA     NA     NA       NA     NA   NA   CAT!
```

I would like to collapse it to the following:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 10
  ID    COLOUR DATE        size1 size2 length1 length2 width1 width2 group1
  <chr> <fct>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <chr>    
2 ID1   RED    2017-07-31  496.    90    344.       NA     NA   NA      NA  
3 ID1   RED    2017-07-31  332.    90    344.       NA     NA   NA      NA  
6 ID1   RED    2017-08-22   NA     NA     NA        NA     NA   NA      NA     
8 ID1   RED    2019-01-29   23     NA     NA        NA     NA   34.7  CAT!
```

Note that where there is more than one value for the ID/Date combination, it repeats the ID and Date combination.  I have tried several ways of doing this, with no success:

**Method 1:**

```
sum_NA <- function(x) {if (all(is.na(x))) x[NA_integer_] else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)}

df %>%
    group_by(ID, DATE) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(sum_NA))

Error in Summary.factor(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), na.rm = TRUE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

^ The above method gives an error.

**Method 2:**

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID, DATE) %>%
    summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(sum_NA))

  ID    DATE       size1 size2 length1 length2 width1 width2
  <chr> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 ID1   2017-07-31  829.    90    344.      NA     NA   NA  
2 ID1   2017-08-22   NA     NA     NA       NA     NA   NA  
3 ID1   2019-01-29   23     NA     NA       NA     NA   34.7
```

^ The above excludes the `COLOUR` and `group1` columns, because they are not numeric, and it also adds the values of the size1 variables that have the same ID / DATE combination.

**Method 3:**

```
df <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = c("ID", "DATE")]
Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df), , lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = c("ID",  : 
  Supplied 2 items for column 2 of group 1 which has 5 rows. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

^ I get an error for the above.

Can anyone help find a solution to this?

Comment: Is there only ever none or 1 valid value per variable per group?

Comment: No, there may be multiple valid values per variable per grouping

Comment: What would be the expected output if you have two or more valid values within a group within a variable?  Your example only has a single (or no) valid value per variable per group so these can be collapsed to a single row.

Comment: Apologies - repetition of the ID and Date

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect the answer to this

Comment: I think your expected output seems to be not doing any `sum`.  Perhaps `sum_NA <- function(x) {if (all(is.na(x)))  first(x) else if(is.numeric(x)) x[!is.na(x)] else first(x[!is.na(x)])}`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above you can try the following and see if it returns your expected result when multiple values might be present:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, COLOUR, DATE) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ na.omit(.x)[1:pmax(first(max(colSums(!is.na(cur_data())))), 1)]), .groups = "drop")

# A tibble: 3 x 10
  ID    COLOUR DATE        siz1 size2 length1 length2 width1 width2 group1
  <chr> <fct>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> 
1 ID1   RED    2017-07-31  496.    90    344.      NA     NA   NA   NA    
2 ID1   RED    2017-08-22   NA     NA     NA       NA     NA   NA   NA    
3 ID1   RED    2019-01-29   23     NA     NA       NA     NA   34.7 CAT!
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a solution that doesn't require across ?